# Graph data modeling (Neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4jphp, nosql

i am new to graph databases. I am having some issues while modeling data. I am working on site which contains information about books.
I have categorized books in different categories like: arts, fiction etc. I ve generated a node for each category. Nodes of categories are **unconnected** with each other and that where the first issue comes. To solve this issue i am going to index a node called category and connect all my category nodes to it which leads me to the second issue of dense node or **super node**.
Now tell me how to solve both these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use labels. The idea of super nodes was for neo4j < 2.*

You can add a label BookCategory and when you want to return back all your bookCategoryNodes, just specify the label in the match query :

```
MATCH (n:BookCategory) RETURN n
```

Comment: yes i am using labels. does labeling actually solve the super node issue?

Comment: yes for sure, it groups your label in fact and it creates automatically an index for them

Comment: that's great! should i leave them unconnected?